# Evaluate absolute value of array element in function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I defined a function

```
def softthresh(u, LAMBDA):
    if np.fabs(u) <= LAMBDA:
        return 0
     else:
        return ((np.fabs(u) - LAMBDA) * u / np.fabs(u))
```

`u` is a `numpy` array, and `np.fabs` will check the relations for each array element `(np.fabs(u_i))`. It gives me the following error:

```
 The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

---

---

Follow up Question:

Strange behaviour in simple function.

```
def softthresh(u,LAMBDA):
    for i in u:
        if np.fabs(i)<=LAMBDA:
            return 0
        else:
            return ((np.fabs(i)-LAMBDA)*u/np.fabs(i)) 
   ll = 5.0
   xx = np.arange(-10,11)
   yy = softthresh(xx,ll)
```

What I get is not what I expect. for u (=xx ) array-elements that are smaller than 5 i should get zero. But i don't. Why?

Comment: To enter the if block, do you want all elements in u to be smaller in absolute value than lambda, or just one of them ?

Comment: Do you not understand the error message? It can't evaluate the result of `np.fabs(u) <= LAMBDA` in a boolean context, because it's not sure what you mean. Could you give some example inputs and outputs/

Comment: Actually, i would like it to work like a function. The if statemant should check for every array element (i.e. x-value) and give the results (y-values) as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `return` from inside the inner loop. Therefore, your function returns just after it evaluates the first member of `u`.

Since you are using NumPy, you should take advantage of NumPy's ability to operate on the whole array at once, and also of NumPy's smart indexing.

```
def softthreshold(u, LAMBDA):
    notzero = np.fabs(u) > LAMBDA # find the indeces of elements that need to be scaled
    rr = np.zeros_like(u) # an array the same size/type as u, already initialized to 0
    rr[notzero] = (np.fabs(u[notzero])-LAMBDA)*u[notzero]/np.fabs(u[notzero]) # scale each of the members that aren't zero
    return rr
```

Comment: Ok nice, this helps alot. Thank you.

But is there a way to do it just like in matlab. a= array, f=function, b=solution_array:

f(a)=b    ? is this somehow possible with my kind of function?

Comment: @user5437072  You can call this just like in your original post - `yy = softthreshold(xx,ll)`. Or did I not understand your follow up question correctly?

Comment: @mtrw this should really not be `np.where` but a simple condition: `notzero = np.fabs(u) > LAMBDA`

Answer (score 0):

If `u` is an array, you need to loop through all its elements in your function.

Alternatively, you can have `u` be an element of your array and call it with a loop like this :

```
tbl = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
for elt in tbl:
    print(softthresh(elt, 3))
```

Results would be :

```
0
0
0
1.0
2.0
```

Comment: still I dont get it >.< see answer below

Answer (score 0):

Your problems depends on the numpy array. If you are working with a list it works.

Otherwise if you need the numpy array you can use code like

```
def softthresh(u,LAMBDA):
for i in u:
    if np.fabs(i)<=LAMBDA:
        return 0
    else:
        return ((np.fabs(u)-LAMBDA)*u/np.fabs(u))
```

You get the array through the dependency of <= logic and the numpy.array definition.